# calculate logarithm of user input without strings or lists

Tags: string, list, input, logarithm

I want to calculate the log2 of a user input. But I can't use strings or lists in log, only real numbers. How do I get the user input into the math.log argument without having to input it manually?
Originally I was going to assign it to the term freq. No Go...

```
freq = input('what frequency do you want to convert to HSB?  ')
import math

logged = math.log(freq, 2)
fint = int(logged)
ffloa = logged - fint
hue = int((ffloa*360)-11)
bri = fint*7
sat = 128 - bri
```

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a user input to a numeric type?  Try `freq=float(input('what frequency do you want to convert to HSB?  '))`

Comment: You Beauty! Thanks so much!